# como guardar en una variable el resultado de ejecutar un comando ssh en java con jsch?

Tags: java, ssh

hace poco estaba averiguando como ejecutar comandos ssh en programas java, y me tope con un post que me recomendaba la libreria jsch. El método que me encontré era el siguiente:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session; 

public static void EjecutarSSH(String pUser, String pPass, String pHost, int pPort, String pComando) throws Exception {
    JSch ssh = new JSch();
    // Instancio el objeto session para la transferencia
    Session session = null;
    // instancio el canal sftp
    ChannelExec channelssh = null;
    try {
        // Inciciamos el JSch con el usuario, host y puerto
        session = ssh.getSession(pUser, pHost, pPort);
        // Seteamos el password
        session.setPassword(pPass);
        // El SFTP requiere un intercambio de claves
        // con esta propiedad le decimos que acepte la clave
        // sin pedir confirmación
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(prop);
        session.connect();

        // Abrimos el canal de sftp y conectamos
        channelssh = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        // seteamos el comando a ejecutar
        channelssh.setCommand(pComando);
        // conectar y ejecutar
        channelssh.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        // Cerramos el canal y session
        if (channelssh.isConnected())
            channelssh.disconnect();
        if (session.isConnected())
            session.disconnect();
    }// end try
}// EjecutarSSH
```

Ahora, mi problema es: **¿como recoger en una variable el resultado del comando ejecutado por el método?**

Por ejemplo si el método ejecutase el comando:

```
(grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} 
END 
{print usage "%"}')
```

Que retorna el consumo en % del **CPU** de la PC, y quisiera guardar en un String el resultado de la ejecución de dicho comando para que luego el propio método lo retorne, **¿como quedaría modificado el método?**

Apreciaría mucho su ayuda. Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con este código:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
consola.setOutputStream(baos);
String cadena=new String(baos.toByteArray());
```

Aunque esta algo diferente al tuyo porque yo inicie la consola, así:

```
ChannelShell consola = (ChannelShell) sesion.openChannel("shell");
```

Pero eso es porque mi objetivo era ejecutar comandos en mi aplicación y que se ejecutaran en el servidor.
Pero ese código te puede servir para probar y adaptarlo a lo que estas haciendo.

Comment: Gracias pero al tratar de inicializar la consola de esa forma me da error. Si pudieses hacer el metodo que te ensenne de la forma en la que crees que funcionaria te lo agradeceria al fin y al cabo solo necesito un metodo en Java que via ssh me ejecute comandos y me devuelva la salida en una variable. Gracias de antemano y saludos.

Comment: Inténtalo con la forma que tienes tu. Ademas creo que la versión del jar que tenemos es distinta: yo tengo la 0.1.31

Comment: Si te sirvio???

Comment: Lo logre hacer de otra forma, cambiando el método, muchas gracias

Comment: Sería bueno que compartieras esa forma, por si a alguien mas le sirve. También si es el caso recuerda aceptar la respuesta que mas te ayudo.